# Faster computation of double for loop?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, memory-efficient

I have a piece of working code that is taking too many hours (days?) to compute.
I have a sparse matrix of 1s and 0s, I need to subtract each row from any other row, in all possible combinations, multiply the resulting vector by another vector, and finally average the values in it so to get a single scalar which I need to insert in a matrix. What I have is:

```
m <- matrix( 
c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), nrow=4,ncol=4,
byrow = TRUE)   

b <- c(1,2,3,4)

for (j in 1:dim(m)[1]){
 for (i in 1:dim(m)[1]){
    a <- m[j,] - m[i,]
    a[i] <- 0L
    a[a < 0] <- 0L
    c <- a*b
    d[i,j] <- mean(c[c > 0])
 }
}
```

The desired output is matrix with the same dimensions of m, where each entry is the result of these operations.
This loop works, but are there any ideas on how to make this more efficient? Thank you

Comment: please provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()`

Comment: @wusel edited, thanks

Comment: there seems to be `NaN` in your output matrix `d`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding yeah, do you think that's a problem?

Comment: @Antonio no problem, just curious if that is as expected

Comment: how large is your real data, matrix `m`?

Comment: @minem sorry for the late reply. in my data n=6663, so the loop runs more than 44 million times

Comment: @Antonio sorry, but can you specify? for `m` nrow = 6663? ncol=? size of `b`?

Comment: @Antonio what are you tying to do with line `a[i] <- 0L`? `a` has length 4, if `i > 4` then the length of `a` will be adjusted. For example: `a<-1:4; a[6] <- 0L` results in `1  2  3  4 NA  0` vector. Do you want this?

Comment: @minem both rows and columns are 6663. a is 6663 as well. your example should not happen

Comment: @minem a[i] <- 0L is because I just need the ith entry to be zero, is a network related thing, they cannot look at each other

Comment: @Antonio how sparse is `m`? proportion of 1`s from all entries?

Comment: @minem very sparse, 1's are only 0.0001074096 of the total. by the way, thanks a lot for helping

Comment: @minem edit: in the second to last comment, I meant they cannot look at _themselves_, not at each other. It's a one-way network, I'm trying to find who are the targets of my target, excluding myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My stupid solution is to use `apply` or `sapply` function, instead of `for` loop to do the iterations:

```
sapply(1:dim(m)[1], function(k) {z <- t(apply(m, 1, function(x) m[k,]-x)); diag(z) <- 0; z[z<0] <- 0; apply(t(apply(z, 1, function(x) x*b)),1,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))})
```

I tried to compare your solution and this in terms of running time in my computer, yours takes

```
t1 <- Sys.time()
d1 <- m
for (j in 1:dim(m)[1]){
  for (i in 1:dim(m)[1]){
    a <- m[j,] - m[i,]
    a[i] <- 0L
    a[a < 0] <- 0L
    c <- a*b
    d1[i,j] <- mean(c[c > 0])
  }
}
Sys.time()-t1
```

Yours needs `Time difference of 0.02799988 secs`. For mine, it is reduced a bit but not too much, i.e., `Time difference of 0.01899815 secs`, when you run

```
t2 <- Sys.time()
d2 <- sapply(1:dim(m)[1], function(k) {z <- t(apply(m, 1, function(x) m[k,]-x)); diag(z) <- 0; z[z<0] <- 0; apply(t(apply(z, 1, function(x) x*b)),1,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))})
Sys.time()-t2
```

You can try it on your own computer with larger matrix, good luck!

Comment: thank you very much, I'm trying to run it now. I just wanted to make sure this does exactly the same thing. could you please explain to me the first part of the function? {z <- t(apply(m, 1, function(x) m[k,]-x))
I'm sorry, apply and sapply are still kind of a mistery to me.. thank you!

Comment: `m[k, ] - x` is to compute the difference between k-th row and another row `x`, and `apply(m,1,function(x) m[k, ] - x)` performs the above for each row within the matrix. You need to use `t()` to transpose the output matrix. @Antonio

Comment: thanks a lot, this works! I haven't accepted the answer yet only in the remote hope of someone else finding an even faster way. I have a very big dataset and this is too slow still..

Comment: Maybe you need to find some approach that simplify your matrix processing in a mathematical way, instead of hacking from the coding perspective only @Antonio

Answer (score 1):

1) create test sparse matrix:

```
nc <- nr <- 100
p <- 0.001
require(Matrix)
M <- Matrix(0L, nr, nc, sparse = T) # 0 matrix
n1 <- ceiling(p * (prod(dim(M)))) # 1 count
M[1:n1] <- 1L # fill only first column, to approximate max non 0 row count
# (each row has at maximum 1 positive element)
sum(M)/(prod(dim(M)))

b <- 1:ncol(M)

sum(rowSums(M))
```

So, if the proportion given is correct then we have at most 10 rows that contain non 0 elements

Based on this fact and your supplied calculations:

```
# a <- m[j, ] - m[i, ]
# a[i] <- 0L
# a[a < 0] <- 0L
# c <- a*b
# mean(c[c > 0])
```

we can see that the result will be meaningful only for`m[, j]` rows which have at least 1 non 0 element

==> we can skip calculations for all `m[, j]` which contain only 0s, so:

```
minem <- function() { # write as function
  t1 <- proc.time() # timing
  require(data.table)
  i <- CJ(1:nr, 1:nr) # generate all combinations
  k <- rowSums(M) > 0L # get index where at least 1 element is greater that 0
  i <- i[data.table(V1 = 1:nr, k), on = 'V1'] # merge
  cat('at moust', i[, sum(k)/.N*100], '% of rows needs to be calculated \n')
  i[k == T, rowN := 1:.N] # add row nr for 0 subset
  i2 <- i[k == T] # subset only those indexes who need calculation
  a <- M[i2[[1]],] - M[i2[[2]],] # operate on all combinations at once
  a <- drop0(a) # clean up 0

  ids <- as.matrix(i2[, .(rowN, V2)]) # ids for 0 subset
  a[ids] <- 0L # your line: a[i] <- 0L
  a <- drop0(a) # clean up 0

  a[a < 0] <- 0L # the same as your line
  a <- drop0(a) # clean up 0

  c <- t(t(a)*b) # multiply each row with vector
  c <- drop0(c) # clean up 0

  c[c < 0L] <- 0L # for mean calculation
  c <- drop0(c) # clean up 0

  r <- rowSums(c)/rowSums(c > 0L) # row means
  i[k == T, result := r] # assign results to data.table
  i[is.na(result), result := NaN] # set rest to NaN
  d2 <- matrix(i$result, nr, nr, byrow = F) # create resulting matrix
  t2 <- proc.time() # timing
  cat(t2[3] - t1[3], 'sec \n')
  d2
}
d2 <- minem()
# at most 10 % of rows needs to be calculated 
# 0.05 sec
```

Test on smaller example if results matches

```
d <- matrix(NA, nrow(M), ncol(M))
for (j in 1:dim(M)[1]) {
  for (i in 1:dim(M)[1]) {
    a <- M[j, ] - M[i, ]
    a[i] <- 0L
    a[a < 0] <- 0L
    c <- a*b
    d[i, j] <- mean(c[c > 0])
  }
}
all.equal(d, d2)
```

Can we get results for your real data size?:

```
# generate data:
nc <- nr <- 6663L
b <- 1:nr
p <- 0.0001074096 # proportion of 1s
M <- Matrix(0L, nr, nc, sparse = T) # 0 matrix
n1 <- ceiling(p * (prod(dim(M)))) # 1 count
M[1:n1] <- 1L

object.size(as.matrix(M))/object.size(M)
# storing this data in usual matrix uses 4000+ times more memory

# calculation:
d2 <- minem()
# at most 71.57437 % of rows needs to be calculated 
# 28.33 sec
```

So you need to convert your matrix to sparse one with

```
M <- Matrix(m, sparse = T)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @minem. I managed to get the desired output with ThomasIsCoding's solution but I see your idea of only computing the needed rows must be the most efficient. It looks complicated to me but I'll try to understand it properly for future reference